# Unable to Update MS-Access Database table using VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

i am trying to update MS-Access database table with the code below using VB.net and i get this Error "Syntax error in UPDATE statement"

```
Dim Dcon As OleDbConnection
Dim Dcom As OleDbCommand
Dcon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & DataSource & ";")

Dcom = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Drivers SET ID=?,First=?,Last=?,Company=?,Addr=?,City=?,ST=?,Zip=?,MobileP=?,HomeP=?,Email=?,DL=?,DateSince=?,DateTerm=?,TruckID=?,Commants=?,Image=? WHERE ID = ID=?", Dcon)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label3.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", TextBox1.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", TextBox2.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", TextBox3.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr", TextBox4.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox5.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", TextBox6.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", TextBox7.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileP", TextBox8.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeP", TextBox9.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox10.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DL", TextBox11.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateSince", TextBox12.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTerm", TextBox13.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckID", TextBox14.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Commants", TextBox15.Text)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", DriverImage)
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label3.Text)
Dcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dcon.Close()
```

I spent hours on google and i am unable to resolve this issue 
this are my Field name
ID, First, Last, Company, Addr, City, ST, Zip, MobileP, HomeP, Email, DL, DateSince, DateTerm, TruckID, Commants, Image they all TEXT

**Can anyone could tell me what is wrong with this syntax**

Answer (score 0):

The words FIRST and IMAGE are reserved keywords in MS-Access Jet SQL. If you want to use them you should use square brackets around them.

Also the syntax for the where clause is wrong. (But this is probably just a typo)

```
Dcom = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Drivers SET " + 
     "ID=?,[First]=?,Last=?,Company=?,Addr=?,City=?," + 
     "ST=?,Zip=?,MobileP=?,HomeP=?,Email=?,DL=?,DateSince=?," + 
     "DateTerm=?,TruckID=?,Commants=?,[Image]=? WHERE ID=?", Dcon)
```

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response, Ok i renamed the fields and corrected syntax and its working
Thank you vm

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax problem at the end of your sql query:

`... WHERE ID = ID=?`

I assume that should be

```
WHERE ID = ?
```

Answer (score -1):

You're adding the ID parameter to your parameter list twice, once at the beginning and end.

```
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label3.Text)
...
Dcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label3.Text)
```

Get rid of one of them.

Comment: No that's correct with positional parameters like the ones used by an oledb driver. You need to repeat the parameter because it is not recognized by its name, but by its position